# Is there a way of dynamically toggling the Highstock navigator to regain vertical space for the chart?

Tags: highcharts

I'd like to be able to be able to dynamically toggle the presence of the Highstock navigator and allow the chart to expand into the vertical space it occupied.

I've tried simply toggling chart.userOptions.navigator.enabled but it has no effect.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906941/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-navigator-in-highcharts-at-runtime) explains how to use .hide() and .show() methods to conceal the individual components of the navigator and scrollbar, but these use visibility:hidden so the space does not become available for the chart. However, using .css({display: 'none'}) works, but the series itself has no .css() method, and I've been unable to find a way of removing the series from just the navigator.

Does anyone know a method to achieve what I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: it's not supported to hide navigator in real time. The best way would be to destroy chart and create new one with disabled navigator.

Other solution is to use workaround provided by Sebastian Bochan. Then you will need to update manually yAxis.height, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/dJbZT/91/

```
        $('#btn').toggle(function () {
            chart.yAxis[0].defaultHeight = chart.yAxis[0].height;
            chart.xAxis[0].defaultHeight = chart.xAxis[0].height;
            chart.yAxis[0].update({
                height: 500 - chart.plotTop - 35
            }, false);
            chart.xAxis[0].update({
                height: 500 - chart.plotTop - 35
            });
            chart.scroller.xAxis.labelGroup.hide();
            chart.scroller.xAxis.gridGroup.hide();
            chart.scroller.series.hide();
            chart.scroller.scrollbar.hide();
            chart.scroller.scrollbarGroup.hide();
            chart.scroller.navigatorGroup.hide();
            $.each(chart.scroller.elementsToDestroy, function (i, elem) {
                elem.hide();
            })
        }, function () {
            chart.yAxis[0].update({
                height: chart.yAxis[0].defaultHeight
            }, false);
            chart.xAxis[0].update({
                height: chart.xAxis[0].defaultHeight
            });
            chart.scroller.xAxis.labelGroup.show();
            chart.scroller.xAxis.gridGroup.show();
            chart.scroller.series.show();
            chart.scroller.navigatorGroup.show();
            chart.scroller.scrollbar.show();
            chart.scroller.scrollbarGroup.show();
            $.each(chart.scroller.elementsToDestroy, function (i, elem) {
                elem.show();
            })
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, Paweł. That partially works for me, having modified it to use the actual height of my containing <div>. When concealing the navigator, the X-axis descends to the bottom of the <div>, and the plotted lines expand to occupy the additional vertical space. But wherever the expanded plotted lines should be below the previous position of the X-axis, they're invisible. I guess it must be caused by some option I'm using but I'm having a hard time tracking down which one by trial and error.

Comment: Okay, could you recreate issue on jsFiddle (just update mine)? I will check this.

Comment: Been distracted but will get to this eventually. I can't repro with static data. I suspect it's a result of me creating the chart first, then adding my series using the addSeries method.

Comment: Could you show your case in jsfiddle? Just first create chart then add series? Or this case in jsfiddle works too? Then I guess you have old version of Highstock.

Comment: The problem seems to be introduced by highcharts-more.js. If you add this line to your jsfiddle, it will demonstrate what I see.
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

Comment: Hard to guess what is the reason, I would just update clipRect of chart with new height: http://jsfiddle.net/dJbZT/94/ (note - you may need to update it's height after every update on a chart, for example in redraw() callback).

Comment: That works, thanks. And so far I haven't seen problems when updating the chart with new series or additional points. However, I get some funky results when changing the size of the enclosing pane and only calling:  

    chart.setSize($('#container').width(), $('#container').height());

Answer (score 0):

There's another way to do this: reduce the chart height by the navigator's height, and set [`chart.reflow`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart.reflow) to `false` to *prevent* the Y-axis from adapting to the new chart height (try setting it to `true` in the fiddle -- notice the flicker when you show / hide the navigator?).

I've added this answer to [the other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32822950/504611), and the demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/dJbZT/148/ (credits to Sebastian Bochan for the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15921982/504611)).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure when highcharts added this ability via options, but this worked for me:

```
    var chart = $('#graphContainer').highcharts();
    chart.options.navigator.enabled = !chart.options.navigator.enabled;
    $('#graphContainer').highcharts(chart.options);
```

Comment: I think you are _not_ modifying the existing chart, but creating a replacement one with the toggled option.

Comment: All of the series data and previously set options remain when you do this, so you are not replacing it or else you would need to rebuild all the options and series data.  This does in fact modify the chart - give it a try.