# Highcharts - Dynamic enable/disable scrollbar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

Im working with highcharts(highstock) + angularJS(without highchart-ng), and I'm having an issue to enable/disable horizontal scrollbar when series data is updated.

Is there some way to dynamically enable or disable the scrollbar according with length of the series, without using chart.destroy()??

Answer (score 4):

Could you be more specific about your problem? In this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/pano907p/6/, chart rescales after adding or updating series.

`$('#btn1').bind('click', function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.addSeries({
      name: 'second',
      data: [6, 7, 8, 9]
    });
  });`

You can also look at this topic: [Is it possible to hide the navigator in highcharts at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906941/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-navigator-in-highcharts-at-runtime) to see hiding navigator funcionality.